# What type of encryption does iOS 8 use for Bluetooth?

Tags: security, bluetooth, ios, encryption

I know that iOS 8 encrypts Bluetooth connections:

https://www.apple.com/br/privacy/docs/iOS_Security_Guide_Oct_2014.pdf
https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht3647

What I don't know is what kind of encryption it uses.  For Airplay, for example, the PDF above says that iOS uses "AES-128 in CTR mode."

What type of encryption does iOS 8 use for Bluetooth?